# Is it possible to set a container or wrapper width with mjml?

Tags: html-email, mjml

I'm using mjml to create HTML emails, and it looks like the default container width is set to 600px. I need this to be wider, is it possible to either override the 600px default, or setup a wrapper or container div where I can adjust the width?

Comment: Questions like this typically get answers within hours at https://mjml.slack.com/. Consider joining us. A friendly group!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://mjml.io/documentation/#mj-body), you can add the width attribute:

```
width="400"
```

I ran a test in their editor and it seemed to work - https://mjml.io/try-it-live

```html
<mjml>
  <mj-body width="400">
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column>
        <mj-text>This is a header</mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
    <mj-section background-color="#e7e7e7">
      <mj-column>
        <mj-social>
          <mj-social-element name="facebook" />
        </mj-social>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```